# Expected value of indicator variables

Tags: mean, random-variable, expected-value

I have an ensemble of graphs with $N$ nodes and $M$ undirected edges each. Let $X_{ij}$ be indicator variables that point to the existence of an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$ on a particular graph. Their expected values in the ensemble are known and given by $p_{ij}$.

$$
X_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if edge ij exists}\\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\left< X_{ij} \right> =
p_{ij}
$$

I want to calculate the following expected value:

$$
E \left[ \frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{ik}} \right]
$$

With the restrictions:

- $\sum_k X_{ik} = K_k > 0$ for all $i$ (meaning there are no disconnected nodes in the graph)
- $X_{ii}=0$ for all $i$ (meaning no self-connections).

I know this can be written as:

$$
E \left[ \frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{ik}} \right] = \sum_{x_{i1}}\dots\sum_{x_{iN}} \left( \frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^{N} x_{ik}}f_{i1}(x_{i1})\dots f_{1N}(x_{iN}) \right), \qquad \sum_k x_{ik} > 0
$$

where $f_{ij}(1)=p_{ij}$ and $f_{ij}(0)=1-p_{ij}$ is the probability distribution of variable $X_{ij}$.

The issue is that I can't find a solution for the nested summations. If I make the assumption that the numerator is independent of the denominator, all of my following results, in the limit of $N \to \infty$, make sense. The assumption I mention is this one:

$$
E \left[ \frac{X_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{ik}} \right] = E\left[ \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^NX_{ik}} \right] E[X_{ij}]
$$

My reasoning is that as $N$ grows, the contribution of $x_{ij}$ to the final sum $\sum_jx_{ij}$ is increasingly small, and for very large $N$, $X_{ij}$ is actually independent of the total sum. Is this approximation appropriate for large $N$?

Thanks.

Comment: even if you assume numerator is independent of the denominator, still $E[1/X]\neq 1/E[X]$

Comment: By large $N$, you mean many nodes or many such graph ensembles? If it is the later, I might have a suggestion. Also, I don't deal with graphs typically but the no connected nodes restriction looks to me implies dependence within each row

Comment: @gunes that is correct! I have fixed the question.